# process exec with bin/bash is not working in JAVA

Tags: java, process, exec

I'm trying to do the below in JAVA but its not working for me: The file opt is empty.
The program: RNAfold calculates structures: reads from file: "seq" and writes to file "opt" the structures.
(It's doing the work when I'm running the command from the terminal)

**the program creates the files: seq, opt

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr1;
try {
   command = "home/ViennaRNA-2.0.7/Progs/RNAfold -T "+Double.toString(tempature)+" --noLP <seq> opt";

   pr1 = rt.exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c",command});

.............
```

Does some one sees a problem with the code?

Comment: You can try read error stream of process.

Comment: Are you sure the path in `command` is correct (missing a leading slash)?

Comment: I've tried it says java.io.FileInputStream@28df8ff1.

Comment: I've tried also /home/ViennaRNA-2.0.7/Progs/RNAfold....

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the error stream and exit code?

```
stderr = pr1.getErrorStream (); 
brCleanUp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stderr));
while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
  System.out.println ("[Stderr] " + line);
}

System.out.println ("Exit code: " + process.exitValue());
```

Also, check that your paths are correct, and specify full paths if possible. "home/ViennaRNA-2.0.7/Progs/RNAfold" without leading slash looks odd, and could be wrong if your current directory is not what you expected.

Comment: when i delete "-c" it writes: 
[Stderr] /bin/sh: Can't open /home/ViennaRNA-2.0.7/Progs/RNAfold -T 39.0 --noLP <seq> opt
problem with file opt

Comment: So it looks like your command is somehow incorrect. Can you run RNAfold from the BASH shell? If so, what does the full command look like?